# MySQL query to check the common time interval and display the interval

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, subquery

I´m looking for some help with the following problem.

I need to check, whether **all selected entries** share a common time interval and if so, what is the time interval.

To visualize the problem:

```
id    openingTime          closingTime
1         09:00                18:00
2         11:00                15:00
3         12:00                20:00
4         21:00                23:00
```

Desired output is to get either an empty result or one result with the overlapping interval.

Examples:

```
selected id    openingTime          closingTime
1,2 =>           11:00                15:00
1,2,3 =>         12:00                15:00
1,3 =>           12:00                18:00
1,2,3,4 =>       empty                empty
```

Having IDs with overlapping intervals, the SQL command is easy:

```
SELECT MAX(openingTime), MIN(closingTime) FROM table WHERE id IN (ids)
```

But this SQL query doesn't deal with the cases when one or more entries are not sharing the same interval.

Here is some sample data and [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sgNwyisNzVrgK6wx5QRecV/1) to try it out:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `openingtime` time NOT NULL,
  `closingtime` time NOT NULL
);



INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`, `openingtime`, `closingtime`) VALUES
(1, '09:00:00', '18:00:00'),
(2, '11:00:00', '15:00:00'),
(3, '12:00:00', '20:00:00'),
(4, '21:00:00', '23:00:00');
```

Thank you for your help.

D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking `exists` and aggregation:

```
select min(openingtime), max(closingtime)
from (
    select t.*, 
        exists (
            select 1
            from mytable t1
            where t1.openingtime > t.closingtime or t1.closingtime < t.openingtime
        ) flag
    from mytable t
) t
having max(flag) = 0
```

The subquery checks if any other row in the table does not overlap with the current row. Then the outer query aggregates, and uses `having` to filter out the whole result if any row was flagged.

Comment: I tried and I'm unable to get the result. Could you please try it on the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sgNwyisNzVrgK6wx5QRecV/1

Comment: @DavidKv: what is wrong with the results? This generates an empty resultset, since not all entries overlap. If you remove the last row from the dataset, it returns a result.

Comment: There is just a small typo in your solution. MAX and MIN are mixed. The other problem is, I need to work it even with the last row in the dataset (not deleting it). Is there a chance to restrict the query somehow by id like this: WHERE id IN (1,2,3) =>12:00 15:00, WHERE id IN (1,4)=>empty

Comment: @DavidKv: `MAX()` is on purpose - that's how we ensure that there is no missing overlap in the whole dataset. To filter, you need a `where` clause in both the query and the subquery. See: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sgNwyisNzVrgK6wx5QRecV/2

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly. I just had to switch MAX and MIN -> MAX(openingtime) and MIN(closingtime), as your solution shows the outer interval of the opening hours and i need to display the inner range. But with this modification it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

A common interval is going to start at an opening time and end at the next closing time.  So, you can test each starting time, counting the number of overlaps.

```
select o.time, min(t.closingtime)
from (select distinct time from t) o join
     t
     on o.time >= t.openingtime and o./time <= t.closingtime
group by o.openingtime
having count(*) = (select count(*) from t);
```

This return no rows if there are no overlaps.  It returns all overlapping periods if there is more than one (which I don't think is possible with one row per id).